# Locking/disable user accounts on HSQL

Tags: hsqldb

Can you lock/disable a user on HSQL?

I'd like to setup a user account before it's needed. Then when needed I'd unlock it so it can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable an account.

However, when a user is created it has no privileges whatsoever. You can delay granting SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE etc privileges until the user account is needed.

The correct way to manage this is to create a ROLE and grant the relevant privileges to this role. When an account is needed, you grant this ROLE to the account. When you want to "suspend" an account, you simply REVOKE this role from the account.

See the Guide: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/accesscontrol-chapt.html